# nftables rules apparently blocking ssh traffic - could it be special characters?

Tags: rhel, firewall, nftables

I have a set of nftable rules of the following form:

```
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ip saddr 11.37.79.97/29 counter packets 0 bytes 0 log prefix "'**A Log Prefix**'"
        ct state established,related counter packets 70 bytes 12769 accept
        iifname "lo" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        ct state new tcp dport 22 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        ip saddr 11.137.79.0/24 ct state new counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "A comment"
        
        ip saddr 11.37.79.0/24 ip daddr 11.37.140.0/22 ct state new counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "another comment"
        ip saddr 11.37.36.0/22 ip daddr 11.37.140.0/22 ct state new counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "another comment"
        ct state new tcp dport 1234 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        ct state new tcp dport 2234 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        ct state new tcp dport 2244 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        tcp dport 61151 ct state new counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "Some Application"
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
  }
}
...

#existing rules from firewall rich rules populating nftables are of the form:

table inet firewalld {
    set OUR-NET {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 11.0.0.0/8 }
    }

    set OUR-VPN {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 72.60.16.0/20, 72.60.144.0/20,
                 72.60.192.0/24 }
    }

    set Management-Support {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 11.37.223.0/24, 11.37.128.0/24,
                 11.37.129.0/24, 11.37.130.0/24}
    }


    chain mangle_PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle + 10; policy accept;
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES
        jump mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_pre {
        jump mangle_PRE_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "ens197" goto mangle_PRE_public
        goto mangle_PRE_public
    }

    chain mangle_PREROUTING_POLICIES_post {
    }

    chain filter_PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        icmpv6 type { nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit } accept
        meta nfproto ipv6 fib saddr . mark . iif oif missing log prefix "rpfilter_DROP: " drop
    }

    chain filter_INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct status dnat accept
        iifname "lo" accept
        jump filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre
        jump filter_INPUT_ZONES
        ct state { invalid } log prefix "STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
        ct state { invalid } drop
        log prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
        reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        ct status dnat accept
        iifname "lo" accept
        ip6 daddr { ::/96} log prefix "IPv4_REJECT: " reject with icmpv6 type addr-unreachable

        jump filter_FORWARD_IN_ZONES
        jump filter_FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
        ct state { invalid } log prefix "STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
        ct state { invalid } drop
        log prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
        reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    }

    chain filter_OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter + 10; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        oifname "lo" accept
        ip6 daddr { ::/96 } log prefix "IPv4_REJECT: " reject with icmpv6 type addr-unreachable
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_POLICIES_pre {
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6
    }

    chain filter_INPUT_ZONES {
        iifname "ens197" goto filter_IN_public
        goto filter_IN_public
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_IN_ZONES {
        iifname "ens197" goto filter_FWDI_public
        goto filter_FWDI_public
    }

    chain filter_FORWARD_OUT_ZONES {
        oifname "ens197" goto filter_FWDO_public
        goto filter_FWDO_public
    }

    chain filter_IN_public {
        jump filter_IN_public_log
        jump filter_IN_public_allow
        meta l4proto { icmp, ipv6-icmp } accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_log {
        ip saddr @Management-Support tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } limit rate 10/minute log prefix "SSH" level info
        ip saddr @OUR-VPN tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } limit rate 10/minute log prefix "SSH" level info
        ip saddr @OUR-NET tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } limit rate 10/minute log prefix "SSH" level info
    }

    chain filter_IN_public_allow {
        ip saddr @Management-Support tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        ip saddr @OUR-VPN tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } accept
        ip saddr @OUR-NET tcp dport 22 ct state { new, untracked } accept
    }

    chain filter_FWDI_public {
        jump filter_FWDI_public_allow
        meta l4proto { icmp, ipv6-icmp } accept
    }

    chain filter_FWDI_public_allow {
        ip saddr @OUR-NET icmp type destination-unreachable icmp code 4 accept
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6 {
        jump filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow
    }

    chain filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6_allow {
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit accept
        icmpv6 type nd-router-advert accept
        icmpv6 type nd-redirect accept
    }
}
table ip firewalld {
    set OUR-NET {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 11.0.0.0/8 }
    }

    set OUR-VPN {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 72.60.16.0/20, 72.60.144.0/20,
                 72.60.192.0/24 }
    }

    set Management-Support {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 11.37.223.0/24, 11.37.128.0/24,
                 11.37.129.0/24, 11.37.130.0/24 }
    }


    chain nat_PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_PREROUTING_ZONES
    }


    chain nat_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "ens197" goto nat_PRE_public
        goto nat_PRE_public
    }


    chain nat_POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES
    }


    chain nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES {
        oifname "ens197" goto nat_POST_public
        goto nat_POST_public
    }
}
table ip6 firewalld {
    set OUR-NET {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 11.0.0.0/8 }
    }

    set OUR-VPN {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 72.60.16.0/20, 72.60.144.0/20,
                 72.60.192.0/24 }
    }

    set Management-Support {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        elements = { 11.37.223.0/24, 11.37.128.0/24,
                 11.37.129.0/24, 11.37.130.0/24,
                 11.37.131.0/24, 11.37.132.0/24,
                 11.37.133.0/24, 11.137.128.0/24,
                 11.137.129.0/24, 11.137.130.0/24,
                 11.137.131.0/24, 11.137.132.0/24,
                 11.137.133.0/24 }
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_PREROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain nat_PREROUTING_ZONES {
        iifname "ens197" goto nat_PRE_public
        goto nat_PRE_public
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat + 10; policy accept;
        jump nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES
    }

    chain nat_POSTROUTING_ZONES {
        oifname "ens197" goto nat_POST_public
        goto nat_POST_public
    }

}
```

In rich rule format, the existing rules are of the form:

```
'rule family=ipv4 source ipset=Management-Support port port=22 protocol=tcp log prefix=SSH level=info limit value=10/m accept'
'rule family=ipv4 source ipset=OUR-NET port port=22 protocol=tcp log prefix=SSH level=info limit value=10/m accept'
'rule family=ipv4 source ipset=OUR-VPN port port=22 protocol=tcp log prefix=SSH level=info limit value=10/m accept'
```

As I understand it:

- The existing rules allow access to port 22 if the source is from one of the IP sets listed in the rich rules.
- The new rules via nftables, drop any INPUT traffic not following the pattern of anything otherwise listed in the INPUT chain.

The INPUT chain should

- log anything with a source address of 11.37.79.97/29
- accept all traffic with already established or related connections
- accept local host traffic
- accept all traffic with destination port 22 (SSH)
- accept all traffic matching the source ip pattern of 11.137.79.x
- accept all traffic matching the source ip pattern of 11.37.79.x - which includes the traffic above that was logged.
- etc.

So the question is, why does the implementation of this block SSH?

My analysis suggests that it is hitting this INPUT chain and the default policy of DROP is being applied (regardless of whether the firewall chains execute first or last - they all hit this INPUT and thus drop).  This default policy of DROP should only execute if nothing in the chain says otherwise.  This implies it isn't evaluating anything else in the chain.  Which leads me to believe there is a syntax error somewhere prior to the SSH dport 22 accept line. And since it is dropping the existing SSH connection, I suspect it has to be the very first line that logs the 11.37.79.97/29 traffic.

Can anyone clarify what is happening?

----UPDATE----

I have switched the order and added accept to the end of the log prefix line.  It now follows the ct state new tcp dport 22 ....line.  I then load it up with `nft -f <filename>` after flushing the ruleset and then did a firewall-cmd --reload.  This has also disconnected me and blocked SSH access.